# Python: Do something then sleep, repeat

Tags: python, python-3.x, sleep

I'm using a little app for Python called Pythonista which allows me to change text colour on things every few seconds. Here's an example of how I've been trying to go about doing this in an infinite loop;

```
while True:
    v['example'].text_color = 'red'
    time.sleep(0.5)
    v['example'].text_color = 'blue'
    time.sleep(0.5)
    # and so on..
```

The issue here is that this freezes my program because Python keeps sleeping over and over, and I never see any change. Is there a way of being able to see the change (the text changing to red/blue/etc) and then doing the next task x amount of time later, and so on?

Comment: You need to look into *multithreading*. Your tasks are all running in one thread — including the graphics. When you say `sleep`, then **everything** sleeps. What you want to do is put your loop into a separate thread with asynchronous callbacks to ensure continuous execution without interrupting the flow of the rest of the program.

Comment: @PierceDarragh Will do, thanks

Comment: No problem! There are tons of tutorials online and many posts here on SO. Best of luck! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create a new thread that runs your code. Put your code in its own method      some_function() and then start a new thread like this:

```
thread = Thread(target = some_function)
thread.start()
```